# Create Schema (Table) using Hibernate

Tags: java

I have a jar file in which there are set of models annotated as @Entity . Now I want to create tables in database corresponding to models in jar file (I can use jar file as in dependency in pom file by installing jar on local repository). And it should be generic (e.g MySQL, Postgresql, oracle, ms sql server, h2....). I am new in hibernate. Can any one suggest me how can I do this.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html follow this tutorial..be more specific about your question.

Comment: This tutorial does not meet problem described above.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport we can achieve this task.
Example :

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
//we can set property here e.g configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");.....
configuration = configuration.configure();
SchemaExport schemaExport  = new SchemaExport(configuration);
schemaExport.create(false, true); //1st parameter indicated to show query on console and 2nd parameter is to create(update) table in database.
```

Answer (score 1):

From [docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) you can use

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto
>
> Automatically validates or exports schema DDL to the database when the
>   SessionFactory is created. With create-drop, the database schema will
>   be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed explicitly.
>
> validate | update | create | create-drop

from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438146/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-possible-values-and-what-they-do)

> 1)validate: validate the schema, makes no changes to the database.
>
> 2)update: update the schema.
>
> 3)create: creates the schema, destroying previous data.
>
> 4)create-drop: drop the schema at the end of the session.

Hope that helps

Comment: It's also useful. But I don't need to drop schema. Thanks