# Hibernate - H2 database is not created

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

I want to use `Hibernate` with `H2` and I want the schema to be created automatically. There are many examples online and my configurations seem fine, but it is not created. Previously I used it with `MySQL` and did not have any problem. Are there additional parameters to be included in anywhere for `H2`?

My persistence unit is defined in `persistence.xml` as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="some.jpa.name"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <!-- tried with and without class property
    <class>some.package.KeywordTask</class>     
    -->
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:./test" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Since show_sql is set to true, I expect to see create statements but nothing happens, i.e. the schema is not created.

I keep my `EntityManagerFactory` as a `final` `static` variable:

```
public static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("some.jpa.name");
```

In some place in my code, I am trying to persist an entity:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
KeywordTask task = new KeywordTask();
task.setKeyword(keywordTask.getKey());
task.setLimit(keywordTask.getValue());
em.persist(task);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

This throws exception with cause:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "KEYWORDTASK" not found;
```

which is expected since the schema is not created.

How can I get the schema created?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25156520/574975) of any help?

Comment: @jaivalis my case is quite simple. I don't know whether it might help but there must be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem was quite unrelated! I am writing it here in case some other guys might face it too, and spend half a day for such a stupid thing.

First, I changed from `H2` to `Derby` to check, and it worked. In this way, I was sure that there was no problem with `persistence.xml` configuration.

After searching around the logs, I realized that hibernate was not able to create the table since one of the properties of the `KeywordTask` entity was `limit`, and it is a reserved word! (Remember the place that I persist an instance and observe the name of the setter: `setLimit`.) After changing the name of the property, it worked.